# Would to express habitual actions in past

Tags: past-habitual

In Portuguese, there is a specific verbal form in past tense for when one expresses habitual actions in past tense. In English, however, we must use **Would**. Its usage is more a matter of "how we speak" rather than "how we should speak", i.e: idiomatic usage rather than grammatical usage.

This is what tricks me. In Portuguese, when we express such actions, we keep the same structure all the way to the end, ex:

> When I was younger, my father **would** take me to a skate park. While we **would** skate around, he **would** clean the car, and then we **would** go home.

As far as I'm concerned, this is gramatically correct, though tiring... 
My question is: Is this how a native speaker would normally say a repeated past action? Or could I simply take out the **Would's**, and replace them for simple past forms:

"When I was younger, my father would take me to a skate park. While I **skated**, he **cleaned** the car, and then we **went** home"

Does it maintain the same meanings: repeated actions, or somehow, change it?

Comment: Also, you can toss in "used to" sentences for the sake of variety in my opinion. Good question though.

Comment: *When I was younger, my father **would take** me to a skate park. While we **skated** around, he **cleaned** the car, and then we **went** home* - or I might just end on contracted *...then **we'd go** home,* since it's no more syllables and it serves to "remind" the hearer that I'm talking about something that happened ***many times***. English isn't as "constrained" by "consistency" as you seem to think. By and large, the simpler it can be without compromising *meaning in context*, the better. The same happens when switching out of Past Perfect within an extended multi-verb utterance.